# How to set a static UITableview on xib?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I want to use the **xib** to setup a static UITableview. 
   How can do to get it?
   I don't find the button to set tableView static or dynamic.
   How about use the **storyboard**?

Comment: please clarify what you mean when you say _static_ or _dynamic_ `UITableView`; you may refer to not handling user-interaction? or disable the scrolling only? or show determined amount of cells? or fixed size on the screen on each device? or what exactly do you want to make _static_ in a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't possible with xibs. If you want to use static cells in your UITableView, you'll have to use storyboard.

Answer (score -2):

Go to `tableView` properties and change `Content` to `Static Cells`, look at this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html)

[image]

Comment: This seems to be possible only with storyboards not in xib files.